# Variance in Dates in SQL Server, Excel and MS Access

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I noticed that when I convert a date into an integer, I get different values in SQL Server, Excel and MS Access.

For example, in SQL server, `SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(DateTime,CONVERT(varchar, '2021-01-01'))) AS MyDate;` gives me 44195.

In Access, `SELECT CLng(#1/1/2021#) AS MyDate;` gives me 44197.

In Excel, `=DATEVALUE("1/01/2021")` also gives me 44197.

Why is the SQL server result less by 2?

Comment: Why are you converting dates to arbitrary integers? Dates aren't integers. How they're stored internally doesn't matter. Excel has no real date type, it stores a *float* and displays it as a date based on the cell style. And the SQL expression is simply wrong. `CONVERT(varchar, '2021-01-01')` does nothing because the string is already a string.  `CONVERT(Datetime)` requires a style parameter, otherwise parsing is affected by the server's locale. You could have just written `cast('2021-01-01' as datetime)` or `cast('2021-01-01' as date)`

Comment: The cast is meaningless anyway. The only way it even runs is that the legacy `datetime` was used. If you used `date` or `datetime2` you'd get an error saying `cast(cast('2021-01-01' as date) as int)`. Don't use such casts

Comment: In any case, 30 years ago, `datetime` was stored as a **float** offset, with the integral part a day offset from `1900-01-01` and the fraction representing an (imprecise) value in a 24-hour day. Excel and Access did the same, starting from ....... `1899-12-30`. If anything, the SQL Server offset makes more sense that Excel's, but neither should be used. If you want to calculate the days since a base date, use `datediff(d,...)`

Comment: Why would you assumed that different system will give you same value ? For `SQL Server` `1900-01-01` is `0` but for Excel, it is `1`. Plus Excel has a `"bug"` that treat `1900` as leap year (inherit from Lotus). That's why there is a different of `2`

Comment: Which brings us back to the first comment - why are you trying to generate such a meaningless value? Is there a real question behind this? Did you try to compare data between Excel and SQL Server and got into trouble due to inappropriate conversions?

Comment: It looks like [Excel for Mac used 1904 as the starting year at some point](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487). I doubt you'll find any files that still use this but that shows that trying to just cast dates to integers is a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because they use different origin dates to define a datetime.

If you want to cast a datetime field to an integer, always choose your own origin date.

For example, when you want to use 1970-01-01 as a reference date, use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, '1970-01-01', '2021-01-01');
```

And if you want to cast it back to a date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, 18628, '1970-01-01')
```

Never rely on implementation details like the default origin date.

Note that you can easily get the origin date by using `SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` for SQL server (1900-01-01) or `SELECT FORMAT(CDATE(0), "Short Date")` in Access (1899-12-30), which reveals the 2-day difference.